# Match string from one column to a partial string in another

Tags: excel

I have two columns. One with a list of companies and the second with strings that include the companies name. I need to have a third column that indicates if the company in column 1 is in column 2.

The following code is to check if company in column 1 (E3) is in column 2 ($A$3:$A$9).

IF(SEARCH(E3,$A$3:$A$9)=1,"Yes","No")

Currently, it only works if the company in column 1 is in the same row of the string that contains the company name in column 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MATCH with wildcards:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&E1&"*",A:A,0)),"Yes","No")
```

[image]

Comment: @spencerh24 if this worked for you, please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.